# How to handle removal of previous elements in cursor based pagination?

Tags: pagination, graphql, relay

Let's say I have the following list of objects:

```
[{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}]
```

and for the sake of simplicity, let's assume I want to show 2 elements per page.

I can query the first page by providing the following arguments: `myQuery(first: 2)`
The second page by using the `endCursor` of the first page (which is the id `2`): `myQuery(first:2, after:2)`

Now let's say I am on the second page, and the element with the id `2` gets removed. I want to move to the previous page, by executing: `myQuery(last:2, before:3)`
This would lead to the first page having only one element (the one with the id `1`), which for me seems as a bad user experience.

Is cursor based pagination not well suited for offset pagination, or how do you handle things? The only thing I can think of, is not refetching the data. In this case the user would still think the object with the id `2` is there.

Answer (score 0):

It was not a clever question. The easiest solution would be to use `myQuery(first: 2)` for the first page. Because I always know the sate, at which page I am.